# Multi-line Conditional Statements in Kivy

Tags: python, if-statement, kivy

How do you do multi-line `if` statements in the kv file?

```
Button:
    on_press:
        if x == 1:
            do_something
            do_something_else
            do_another_thing
```

It would be a burden to write

```
if x == 1: do_something
if x == 1: do_something_else
if x == 1: do_another_thing
```

Comment: try with: `if x == 1: do_something; do_something_else; do_another_thing`

Comment: @eyllanesc it worked, however, it looks a little messy being in one line. If I did:

```if x == 1: do_something
if x == 1: do_something_else
if x == 1: do_another_thing```

would that take a lot of processing power, or will it be the same?

Comment: It is the same, your method only has 2 `if` of more, how long do you think an `if` consumes? nothing comparing it to what a GUI does.

Comment: Although for my taste that task I prefer to do it on the python side. I prefer to have a clean .kv oriented to the view taking advantage of its advantage since it generates a clean code, and the logic to python.

Answer (score 1):

After showing my friend my preposterous answer, he pointed out that python does have a multi-line solution, the backslash. Celebrations!

```
    on_release:
        if root.ids.Monolith.background_color == root.BLUECOLOR: 
        app.root.current = "main"; \
        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"; \
        root.ids.Monolith.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.FOD.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.No_Aerogel.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Soft.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Dents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Bents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Creases.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Lines.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Holes.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ; \
        root.ids.Monolith.text          = ""  ; \
        root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.text   = ""  ; \
        root.ids.FOD.text               = ""  ; \
        root.ids.No_Aerogel.text        = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Soft.text              = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Dents.text             = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Bents.text             = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Creases.text           = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Lines.text             = ""  ; \
        root.ids.Holes.text             = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a dumb trick out.

If you want code to be out-of-site-out-of-mind like mine

```
        if root.ids.Monolith.background_color == root.BLUECOLOR: 
        app.root.current = "main" 
        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        root.ids.Monolith.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR 
        root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.FOD.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.No_Aerogel.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Soft.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Dents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Bents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Creases.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Lines.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Holes.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR
        root.ids.Monolith.text          = "" 
        root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.text   = "" 
        root.ids.FOD.text               = "" 
        root.ids.No_Aerogel.text        = "" 
        root.ids.Soft.text              = "" 
        root.ids.Dents.text             = "" 
        root.ids.Bents.text             = "" 
        root.ids.Creases.text           = "" 
        root.ids.Lines.text             = "" 
        root.ids.Holes.text             = ""
```

Then use ; to separate all of your expressions on one line! Isn't Kivy Amazing!!??

```
        if root.ids.Monolith.background_color == root.BLUECOLOR: app.root.current = "main";root.manager.transition.direction = "right";root.ids.Monolith.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR ;root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.FOD.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.No_Aerogel.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Soft.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Dents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Bents.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Creases.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Lines.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Holes.background_color = root.WHITECOLOR;root.ids.Monolith.text          = "" ;root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.text   = "" ;root.ids.FOD.text               = "" ;root.ids.No_Aerogel.text        = "" ;root.ids.Soft.text              = "" ;root.ids.Dents.text             = "" ;root.ids.Bents.text             = "" ;root.ids.Creases.text           = "" ;root.ids.Lines.text             = "" ;root.ids.Holes.text             = "" ;root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Monolith.background_color, "Monolith");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.FOD_yellow_blue.background_color, "FOD_yellow_blue");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.FOD.background_color, "FOD");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.No_Aerogel.background_color, "No_Aerogel");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Soft.background_color, "Soft");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Dents.background_color, "Dents");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Bents.background_color, "Bents");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Creases.background_color, "Creases");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Lines.background_color, "Lines");root.on_text_validate_SecondWindow_Color(self,root.ids.Holes.background_color, "Holes")
```